# OpenGL 2D Transform matrix confusion

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I've been learning OpenGL 3+ from various online resources and recently gotten confused with transformation (model) matrices. As far as I know the proper order of multiplication is `translationMatrix * rotationMatrix * scaleMatrix`. If I understand correctly the multiplication is backwards, so the scale is applied first, then the rotation and lastly the transformation.

I have a `Transform` class which stores the position, scale and origin as 2d vectors and rotation as a float. The method for calculating transformation matrix looks like this:

```
glm::mat4 Transform::getTransformationMatrix() const
{
    glm::mat4 result = glm::mat4(1.0f);

    result = glm::translate(result, glm::vec3(position, 0.0f));
    result = glm::translate(result, glm::vec3(origin, 0.0f));
    result = glm::rotate(result, rotation, glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));
    result = glm::translate(result, glm::vec3(-origin, 0.0f));
    result = glm::scale(result, glm::vec3(scale, 0.0f));

    return result;
}
```

Here's the vertex shader code:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec2 position;

uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

void main()
{
    gl_Position =  projectionMatrix * modelMatrix * vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

As you can see I first translate and then rotate and scale, which is the opposite of what I have learnt. **At first I had it the proper way (scale, rotate and translate) but it rotated around the initial position with huge radius, not the translated position which is not what I want (I am making a 2d game with sprites)**. I don't understand why does it work this way, can someone explain, do I have to keep separate methods for transform matrix calculations? Also does it work the same in 3d space?

Comment: Are you still experiencing problems with this code or are you just asking why it works? You might want to have a look at [my blog post about matrix math](http://nicoschertler.wordpress.com/2012/01/27/directx-and-matrices/). Keep in mind that the article is about DirectX where matrices are transposed and therefore, the order is reversed. But if you keep that in mind, it should be no problem

Comment: It works just fine the way it is now. So no, I am not experiencing these problems anymore. I just don't understand why it works this way. I will check out your link. Thank you.